# iOS - Segue triggered by a tableView accessory?

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

I am trying to display a modal after the accessoryView on a cell is selected.

I currently have a segue from my TableViewCell to display a modal, and I manually call performSegueWithIdentifier on this segue when the accessory button is clicked.

The problem is that the segue gets triggered from both selecting a cell and selecting an accessory view. I only want the segue to be triggered on accessory view selection.

What are the solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a segue by dragging from my first ViewController to the SecondViewController, Instead of dragging from cell to viewController. I manually call performSegueWithIdentifier with the specified identifier string, this way the segue gets called only when I want it to.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on your prototype tableViewCell with the detail accessory in the storyboard.  This  brings up a black connection box.  Under Triggered Segues there are two choices, selection and accessory action.  Control drag from those to your desired view controllers.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?  I am booted to Snow Leopard at the moment and 4.2 does not have a Triggered Segues section for the cell, just one for the "Storyboard Segue".  In 4.6.1, there is a Triggered segues section.  Is it possible to patch this to work in 4.2?

Comment: Boom! This did it for me!